# Number of cells in a keras LSTM is not equal to the number of time steps

Tags: neural-network, lstm

I am trying to understand sequenctial model of LSTM.

In this example: https://its-ml.de/index.php/plattscaling/, the number of time steps is 50.

However, the number of cells in LSTM layer-1 is 100.

Can somebody please explain how is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The number of time steps depends on the input sequence, not on the LSTM itself.

The "number of cells" is the dimensionality of the vectors computed by the LSTM.